# Why is it that input throws a different exception type when given non english text

Tags: python-2.7

input is not meant for strings (python 2.7) and will throw a NameError when the user feeds it with latin text.

If instead it is given non english text (say cyrillic) it will throw a SyntaxError

Why is that?

Comment: that's because only ASCII is allowed in python expressions.

Answer (score 0):

see `input` as an expression evaluator (which is unsafe like `eval` and has been replaced by a strict string input in Python 3.

So it's like you're typing identifiers in the console:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> fac
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'fac' is not defined
>>>
```

`fac` is a *valid identifier* (because it complies to ASCII standard beside other considerations) but not defined, hence the `NameError`

now (using french accents)

```
>>> féc
  File "<interactive input>", line 1
    fÃ©c
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

note that the parsing stopped at the first non-ASCII char, so no identifier has been looked up. `SyntaxError` was here first.

Now, it seems that you need `raw_input()` to be able to enter strings (or enter your cyrillic strings between quotes).